# Start Electron application with Selenium WebDriver using command line arguments

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, electron

I have an Electron application (`chat.exe`) and using the following code snippet I can start it with *Chromedriver*:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary(System.getenv("CHAT")); // CHAT = path to Chat.exe
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

My question is: how can I start it with command line arguments?

e.g. `chat.exe -- --electronPort 5000 --webpackPort 3000 --accessToken 123456789`

I tried the following way but didn't worked:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary(System.getenv("CHAT")); // CHAT = path to Chat.exe
options.addArguments("-- --electronPort 5000 --webpackPort 3000 --accessToken 123456789");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The following error is displayed:

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following format worked (as @user861594 specified):

```
options.addArguments("<Key>=<value>");
```

However, the issue is that the chromedriver cannot take arguments in camelCase format. After the developers modified the syntax of the cli args from camelCase to hyphens, the above solution worked.

e.g.

```
options.addArguments("electron-port=5000");
options.addArguments("webpack-port=3000");
options.addArguments("access-token=12345‌​6789");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");
```

is to **set a Chrome executable in a non-standard location**, not to set any other executable than chrome. Because you had provided other than chrome binary (CHAT.exe in your case) driver opens CHAT not chrome browser and complaining chrome not reachable.

Webdriver is for automating web applications only not for standalone applications automation. For that you can use other tools like "AutoIt".

Comment: [Selenium Webdriver](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver.md) can be used also for automating desktop applications, which are created with web technologies (e.g. [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)) and I have a lot of scenarios up and running.

Comment: > In order to use chromedriver with Electron you have to tell it where to find Electron and make it think Electron is the Chrome browser.

Comment: In that case it looks like your problem is passing arguments to the app which reacts as chrome. The syntax for passing argument is options.addArguments("<Key>=<value>"); So you should try by setting each option like  options.addArguments("electronPort=5000"); options.addArguments("webpackPort=3000");options.addArguments("accessToken=123456789");

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried that way as well, but still not working.